# Python 3: test command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie to Python. I'd like to code a script running on Linux.
To test if user enter all the script arguments:

- If user type: myscript => `print "Usage: myscript [Dir] [Old] [New]"`
- If user type: myscript Dir => `print "Please enter Old and New"`
- If user type: myscript Dir Old => `print "Please enter New"`
- If user type all the required arguments, then execute the main().

How to code myscript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len (sys.argv) < 4:
        print ( ['Usage: myscript [Dir] [Old] [New]',
            'Please enter Old and New',
            'Please enter New'] [len (sys.argv) - 1] )
```

Or you can use argparse. This will not do what you asked for in the question, but it will hopefully placate J.F. Sebastian.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser (description = 'What your program does.')
    p.add_argument ('dir', metavar = 'dir', type = str, help = 'The directory')
    p.add_argument ('old', metavar = 'old', type = str, help = 'The old value')
    p.add_argument ('new', metavar = 'new', type = str, help = 'The new value')
    args = p.parse_args ()
```

Comment: 1. use `!=` to assert the exact number of arguments 2. usage is incorrect. `[]` means "optional" but all arguments are required in this case.

Comment: Yeah. 1. The square brackets are taken from OP's question as the strings to be returned for each number of arguments. Your comment should go under the question, not under this answer. 2. If I used `!=` what use would be indexing the list of strings to be printed?

Comment: The OP doesn't know better but you should if you are answering the question. Just print the usage or use argparse module to provide regular usage string and error reporting.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I haven't downvoted you. type and metavar (maybe) are unnecessary here.

Comment: My own is not working...don't know why when no argument enter? <cut>                                                              if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv[0]) != 1:
        print ("Usage: myscript.py [Dir] [Old] [New]")
    elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print ("Please enter Dir.")
    elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print ("Please enter Old.")
    elif len(sys.argv) < 4:
        print ("Please enter New.")
    main()

Comment: @T_K not `if len(sys.argv[0]) != 1` but `if len(sys.argv) != 1` if anything.

Comment: `len(sys.argv[0])` is the length of the first argument, generally the name of the executable, in your case: python. `len(sys.argv)` is the number of arguments including the executable. So if you call your script without arguments, `len(sys.argv)` equals 1, if you call it with one argument `len(sys.argv)` equals 2, if you call it with n arguments, `len(sys.argv)` equals `n + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the value of `len(sys.argv)`. Note that the first argument will be the python file name itself.

Like this:

```
import sys

argc = len(sys.argv)

if argc < 2:
    print "Usage: myscript [Dir] [Old] [New]"
    sys.exit();
elif argc < 3:
    print "Please enter Old and New"
    sys.exit();
elif argc < 4:
    print "Please enter New"
    sys.exit();

main()
```

Comment: How to do that ? an example.

Comment: It is better to choose an answer for your questions to keep getting support from the community.

Answer (score 0):

All arguments that are passed when running your script will be placed in `sys.argv`. You have to `import sys` first. And then go through the arguments as you would like to. You might consider counting how many arguments you have to decide what to do. And note that the first argument is always the name of your script.

Comment: If you run: `myscript` then `sys.argv == ['myscript']`. If you run: `myscript dir` then `sys.argv == ['myscript', 'dir']`. Understood?

Comment: Ah, Ok. Understood. Thnaks.